# Showing JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly when I check Maven version in windows 10

Tags: java, maven

Today I installed Java 16 and updated proper path in JAVA_HOME environment variable. But still when I run mvn -version command I am getting,

**The JAVA_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly
This environment variable is needed to run this program
NB: JAVA_HOME should point to a JDK not a JRE**

[image]

Comment: Could you execute `SET MAVEN_BATCH_ECHO=on` and next try `mvn -v` again? It might show you the issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take the \bin off your JAVA_HOME variable.

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing this for future me's bc after all the links in StackOverflow, the solution was to check `mvn.cmd` file on `C:\Program Files\Maven\apache-maven-3.6.3\bin`...

On [line 52](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W5iMd.png) it sets the JDK, but it didn't had the "`/bin`" where my `OpenJDK 15` stored the **java.exe**

This fixed the issue on Windows 11. Hope that it helps!